# Rails 5 blank page when click a link

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I am trying to install TrustLogo from Comodo on my site… so, I have this in the `<head>` section:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ 
      var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      //]]>
</script>
```

The problem with this, is that when I visit the page http://localhost:3000 the home page loads fine;

But if I try to click any link, the page doesn’t load;

Pressing F5 or the reload button, it loads fine

So I try to do this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'https://secure.comodo.com/trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

but this causes the same issue.

I tried to change the location too, so I go to `application.js` and add the following:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function(){
  var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
  document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
});
```

but this gives me the following HTML result (blank page)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://www.trustlogo.com/trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">#comodoTL {display:block;font-size:8px;padding-left:18px;}</style>
</head>
</html>
```

Any ideia?

UPDATE:

Moving the code outside of `<head>` like suggested by @patkoperwas, but the page still being blank and got following error in the console:

> turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
>       at n.t.SnapshotRenderer.n.findFirstAutofocusableElement (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at n.t.SnapshotRenderer.n.focusFirstAutofocusableElement (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6
>       at n.t.Renderer.t.renderView (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at n.t.SnapshotRenderer.n.render (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at Function.t.Renderer.t.render (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at e.t.View.e.renderSnapshot (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at e.t.View.e.render (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at r.t.Controller.r.render (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)
>       at r. (turbolinks.self-1d1fddf91adc38ac2045c51f0a3e05ca97d07d24d15a4dcbf705009106489e69.js?body=1:6)

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: nothing strange on logs: `Completed 200 OK in 50ms (Views: 45.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)`

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ 
      var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
      document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
      //]]>
</script>
```

Into the `<body>` instead of the `<head>`. According to the [Turbolinks Documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#working-with-script-elements):

> Turbolinks evaluates `<script>` elements in a page’s `<body>` each time it renders the page. You can use inline body scripts to set up per-page JavaScript state or bootstrap client-side models.

What is happening is that that script is run and evaluated the first time the page loads and when you refresh. On page changes, the script is not re-run (because it is in the `<head>`), so nothing happens.

Comment: hi @patkoperwas check my UPDATE please. Still getting the same blank page and error in  the browser console